# Getting Dispatcher in Lockscreen (Assigned-access) mode in a timer callback

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm having some trouble getting the dispatcher using the GetCurrentView() method. As stated on MSDN I should be using CoreApplication.GetCurrentView() if my app is running in assigned access mode.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/partnerapps/create-a-kiosk-app-for-assigned-access

However GetCurrentView() causes an exception when used in a timer callback.

Anybody have a suggestion how I can get this to work in assigned access mode?
Here's my code with comments about what does, and doesn't work.

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    private Timer timer;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            IsAssignedAccess = LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView() != null;
        }
        catch
        {
            IsAssignedAccess = false;
        }

        // This works fine
        OnTimerAsync();

        // From timer callback OnTimerAsync() doesn't work (see below)
        this.timer = new Timer((e2) => { OnTimerAsync(); }, null, (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds,
            (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds);

    }

    private async void OnTimerAsync()
    {
        if (App.IsAssignedAccess)
        {
            // This causes the app to crash in assigned access mode
            await CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { /* void */ });
        }
        else
        {
            // This works fine in desktop mode, but doesn't work in assigned access mode (lockscreen app)
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { /* void */ });

            // This line below causes app to crash when called from timer callback, but works fine when called directly from OnLaunched();
            var curView = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();
            /*
                * Exception details when called from timer callback
                * Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in LockScreenTest.exe
                * WinRT information: Kan element niet vinden. (Translated: Cannot find element)
                */

            var curDispatch = curView.Dispatcher;
            await curDispatch.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { /* void */ });
        }
    }

    public static bool IsAssignedAccess { get; private set; }
}
```

PS.
This is an example with a timer, I'm also using NFC/SmartCard and other async libraries which have similar problems on event triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using the DispatcherHelper class from MvvmLight to replace the GetCurrentView() method.

This class sets a static reference to the Dispatcher upon app startup which is then later used from wherever you need it (e.g. exactly that what i -thought- GetCurrentView() was supposed to do)

See this (excellent) article for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630646.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396